# How do I recreate this particular academic white paper format?

Tags: academic-writing, tools

I want to produce a similar format like this example:

https://basicattentiontoken.org/BasicAttentionTokenWhitePaper-4.pdf

How can I do this in Google Docs? Is there a specific program that scholars use? I want that particular look and formatting but I don't know what it's called.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about writing but about formatting.

Comment: A question about, say, academic templates on Latex or  formatting in Scrivener would be on-topic, though. Perhaps the issue is that this is asking the wrong question - not, "how can I do this in Google docs?" but "how do I learn how to format an academic paper?"  There are style guidelines for journals that OP may be unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Special" template or program that does this for people in google doc.  I do believe word has built in tools to help with headings but from a quick google, this does not seem to be possible in google docs.  This is something that is usually done manually.  Essentially, you are looking for something to follow an outlined template such as:

Abstract

xxxxxxx

1 Title

xxxxxx

1.1 sub title

xxxxxx

2 title

repeat as needed.  The following link on [Formatting Headings](https://writingcommons.org/open-text/writing-processes/format/apa-format/702-formatting-headings-and-subheadings-apa) may also help you with what you are looking for.  You may also want to check the [add-on store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/heading-numbers/pomhgonejhponfnckfnonolnciipappm?hl=en-US) for chrome/google where you add things like add blocker plus.  A quick search there seemed to pull up some results but not sure if it does what you need but at least it points you in a direction!